# Why Lua 5.3 can not find the path of include (missing: LUA_INCLUDE_DIR)

Tags: lua, centos, include-path

Good day,
I recently could install Lua 5.3 to /opt/lua53 on Centos 7
I also added the following line into /etc/bashrc

```
PATH=/opt/lua35/bin:$PATH
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/lua53/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export PATH LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LUA_INCLUDE_DIR=/opt/lua53/include
```

My colleague also install a software and when I compile by doing

```
make
```

I got the following errors

> [root@pc6 jixie]# make
>   -- Release Build
>   -- Could NOT find Lua (missing: LUA_INCLUDE_DIR) (Required is at least version "5.2")
>   -- Could NOT find ZEROMQPP (missing: ZEROMQPP_LIBRARIES ZEROMQPP_INCLUDE_DIRS) 
>   -- Could NOT find OPENVDB (missing: OPENVDB_LIBRARIES OPENVDB_INCLUDE_DIRS) 
>   -- Downloading/updating kdtree
>   -- Configuring done
>   -- Generating done

I look into serveral thread but none of then could help me.

As I wrote, I added the following line

```
export LUA_INCLUDE_DIR=/opt/lua53/include
```

hoping it can provide the path to LUA_INCLUDE_DIR, but unfortunately I still get the same error.

Any idea how I can solve my problem? DO you need more information of my system?

**NB: I am using cmake 3.10**

Comment: `PATH=/opt/lua35/bin:$PATH` looks wrong: It should be `/opt/lua53/bin`.

Answer (score 2):

`PATH=/opt/lua35/bin:$PATH` looks wrong: It should be `/opt/lua53/bin`.

Comment: OUps, that right, thank but it did not solve the problem. After correcting the misspelling, I got a new error message regarding LUA_LIBRARY: Could NOT find Lua (missing: LUA_LIBRARIES LUA_INCLUDE_DIR) (Required is at least version "5.2")

Comment: @martin10, perhaps you need `export LUA_LIBRARIES=/opt/lua53/lib`?

Comment: @ihf, Thank for your suggestion but it did not help

Comment: Adding this line to my CmakeList.txt file, would it help? set(LUA_INCLUDE_DIR "/opt/lua53"). I installed LUA in /opt/lua53. How would you do? Tks

Answer (score 1):

You are re-inventing the wheel and making it square this time round...

If you have installed Lua development (package or from source) then there should be a package-config file named `lua.pc` placed at a location where `cmake` or `configure` can find it and enquire it as to what should the libs and cflags of any application requiring Lua include/libs. For my system, these files are usually located at `/usr/lib64/pkgconfig/` and indeed `lua.pc` lives there with this content:

```
V= 5.3
R= 5.3.4
prefix= /usr
exec_prefix=${prefix}
libdir= /usr/lib64
includedir=${prefix}/include

Name: Lua
Description: An Extensible Extension Language
Version: ${R}
Requires:
Libs: -llua -lm -ldl
Cflags: -I${includedir}
```

The above file tells `configure` where the include dir is, and what's more important, what flags to use during compilation (-I... -L... -l...).

If you are on a system with a package manager (say `yum`, `dnf`, `apt-get`, etc.) then placing these pc files to their location is taken care of automatically if they exist in the package that is.

If you insist to do it the way you have done it above by hand-coding `LUA_INCLUDE_DIR` to your shell's environment, then make sure that `LUA_INCLUDE_DIR` points to an existing and valid location with valid content. Are you sure the include files required can be found in that dir? Maybe there is an extra dir in there?